# bootstrap doesn't break on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made [this](http://www.sidebyside-india.org/) website with Bootstrap 3 and when I resize my browserwindow the mobile version with custom navbar switches to the correct layout.

But on my mobile device (tested on iPhone) it seems that the website doesn't break on the last breakpoint. It gives me a zoomed out version without the mobile navbar etc.

My viewport settings are the standard settings from bootstrap.

Actually I don't have a clue where to start looking to fix this problem... 
Someone has an idea? Than I can pass you some code to look further.

Thanks!

Comment: look to your css, If there's a problem with your styling, it's there (or should be, anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is majorly because you are using an iframe, why do you have to use an iframe is the serious question I have in my mind..... lose the iframe i guess

I viewed the link that you're calling in the iframe, `test.sidebyside-india.org` and it works fine on the iPhone..

So the reason is definitely the iframe, I would never use an iframe in any responsive design though...

Comment: wasn't aware that the site is in an iframe... 
could that be because of the redirecting to the test.sidebyside-india.org?

Comment: That's indeed the issue. Thanks for your help, solved my problem. :-) !

Answer (score 0):

It's a very old thread, but i had the same issue and the problem was i missed the `meta` for viewport:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

ps: Bootstrap v4